# Pass from one activity the other one

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, android-handler

I have implemented an app that connects to a sensor via Bluetooth and receives data from it. There are two Activities between which I want to pass. First one is `ConnectionScreen` where the connection logic is made, and second, `ActivityTypes`, to which I want to "jump" from the first one.

I've tried to do this in the `Handler` I have in the `ConnectionScreen` but I don't know how.. I also found that it must be done using `BroadcastReceiver` but same problem.
Here is the more important code from these two activities:

```
public class ConnectionScreen extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "DeviceListActivity";
    private static final boolean D = false;
    private static  ArrayList<ActivityEntity> ActivityEntityList = new ArrayList<ActivityEntity>();
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 2;
    private static ArrayList<CustomizedBluetoothDevice> mDeviceList;
    private static ListView mListViewDeviceList;
    private Button mButtonStartScan;
    private int currentPosition;

    private static String mCurrentDeviceAddress = null;
    private static String mConnectedDeviceName = null;
    private static ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    public static BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;
    private static BluetoothMeterService mChatService = null;

    public static final int MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE = 1;
    public static final int MESSAGE_READ = 2;
    public static final int MESSAGE_WRITE = 3;
    public static final int MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME = 4;
    public static final int MESSAGE_TOAST = 5;
    public static final String DEVICE_NAME = "device_name";
    public static final String TOAST = "toast";

    public static DeviceListAdapter mBaseAdapter;
    private static Context context;

    public static void updateUI() {
        mBaseAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(context, mDeviceList, R.layout.macaddr1);
        mListViewDeviceList.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);
    }



  private void getPairedDevice() {
        Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
            for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
                CustomizedBluetoothDevice customizedDevice = new CustomizedBluetoothDevice(
                        device);
                if(customizedDevice.getAddress().equals(mCurrentDeviceAddress)){
                    customizedDevice.setStatus(Constants.STATE_CONNECTED);
                }
                mDeviceList.add(customizedDevice);
            }
        }
    }



 private void initialization() {
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            finish();
            return;
        }

        mBaseAdapter = new DeviceListAdapter(ConnectionScreen.this, mDeviceList, R.layout.macaddr1);

        mListViewDeviceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_devicelist);
        mListViewDeviceList.setAdapter(mBaseAdapter);
        mListViewDeviceList.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener);
        mButtonStartScan = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_startScan);
        mButtonStartScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setup();
                doDiscovery();
            }
        });

        // Register the BroadcastReceiver
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

        filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED);
        this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    public static void startConnect(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device) {
        launchActivity(context, device.getAddress());
    }
// The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
// It will auto-connect with the device.
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int position, long arg3) {
        // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mDeviceList.get(position).getAddress());
        currentPosition = position;
        if (device.getBondState() == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
            unpairDevice(device);
        }
        else {
            pairDevice(device);
        }
    }
};


  /**
     * Start device discover with the BluetoothAdapter
     */
    private void doDiscovery() {
        // If we're already discovering, stop it
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }

        // Request discover from BluetoothAdapter
        mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

    }

    private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            if (D)
                Log.d(TAG, "Start Pairing...");

            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
            m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }
private void unpairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        Method m = device.getClass()
                .getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
// changes the title when discovery is finished

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed
            // already

            CustomizedBluetoothDevice mDevice = new CustomizedBluetoothDevice(
                    device);
            if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                if (mDeviceList.contains(mDevice) == false) {
                    mDeviceList.add(mDevice);
                    updateUI();
                }
            }

        }
        // When the device bond state changed.
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
            int prevBondState = intent.getIntExtra(
                    BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, -1);
            int bondState = intent.getIntExtra(
                    BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);

            if (prevBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED
                    && bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (currentPosition != -1
                        && currentPosition < mDeviceList.size()) {
                    CustomizedBluetoothDevice mDevice = mDeviceList
                            .get(currentPosition);
                    if (device.getAddress().compareTo(mDevice.getAddress()) == 0) {
                        mDevice.setStatus(0);
                        updateUI();
                        pairDevice(device);
                    }
                }
            } else if (prevBondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING
                    && bondState == BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent
                        .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (currentPosition != -1
                        && currentPosition < mDeviceList.size()) {
                    CustomizedBluetoothDevice mDevice = mDeviceList .get(currentPosition);
                    if (device.getAddress().equals(mDevice.getAddress())) {
                        updateUI();
                        startConnect(mDevice);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
};




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_device_list);
    context = this; initialization();
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, ConnectionScreen.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        // Otherwise, setup the chat session
    } else {
        setup();
    }

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
}

private void setup() {
    mDeviceList = new ArrayList<CustomizedBluetoothDevice>();
    currentPosition = -1;
    getPairedDevice();
    updateUI();
}



public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case ConnectionScreen.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT:
            // When the request to enable Bluetooth returns
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // Bluetooth is now enabled, so set up a chat session
                setup();
            } else {
                // User did not enable Bluetooth or an error occured
                if (D)
                    Log.d(TAG, "BT not enabled");
                Toast.makeText(this, R.string.bt_not_enabled_leaving,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    // Unregister broadcast listeners
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}
public static void launchActivity(Context context, String deviceAddress){
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mCurrentDeviceAddress = deviceAddress;
    mChatService = new BluetoothMeterService(context, mHandler);
    connectDevice();
    if (mChatService != null) {
        if (mChatService.getState() == Constants.STATE_NONE) {
            mChatService.start();
        }
    }

}
// Automatically try to connect with the known mac address;
private static class ConnectThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothDevice device;
    public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice d) {
        this.device = d;
    }
    public void run() {
        while (mConnectThread == Thread.currentThread()) {
            if (mChatService.getState() == Constants.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Log.e(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTED");
                break;
            } else if (mChatService.getState() == Constants.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                try {
                    Log.e(TAG, "STATE_CONNECTING");
                    mChatService.connect(device);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            } else
                try { Log.e(TAG, "STATE_DISCONECTED");
                    mChatService.start();
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
        }
    }
}
    // create the bluetooth device object, and try to connect with it
    // consistantly and automatically.
    private static void connectDevice() {
        if (mCurrentDeviceAddress == null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Bluetooth MAC address is not assigned.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(mCurrentDeviceAddress);
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
    }

    // The Handler that gets information back from the BluetoothMeterService
    private static final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            Log.e(TAG, msg.toString());
            switch (msg.what) {
                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case Constants.STATE_CONNECTED:
                            Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_CONNECTED");
                            for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                                if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                    device.setStatus(Constants.STATE_CONNECTED);
                                }
                            }
                            updateUI();
                            break;
                        case Constants.STATE_CONNECTING:
                            Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_CONNECTING");
                            for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                                if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                    device.setStatus(Constants.STATE_CONNECTING);
                                }
                            }
                            updateUI();
                            break;
                        case Constants.STATE_NONE:
                            Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_NONE");
                            for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                                if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                    device.setStatus(Constants.STATE_NONE);
                                }
                            }
                            updateUI();
                            break;
                        case Constants.STATE_DISCONNECTING:
                            Log.e(TAG, "handler - STATE_DISCONNECTING");
                            for(CustomizedBluetoothDevice device : mDeviceList){
                                if(device.getAddress() == mCurrentDeviceAddress){
                                    device.setStatus(Constants.STATE_DISCONNECTING);
                                }
                            }
                            updateUI();
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_WRITE:
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    Log.e(TAG, "handler - MESSAGE_READ " + readMessage);

                    HrmReading hrm = new HrmReading( readBuf );
                    ActivityEntity activity = hrm.getAllInfo();
                    activity.setStartDateTime(null);
                    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                    activity.setCurrentDateTime(timeStamp);
                    activity.setEndDateTime(null);
                    ActivityEntityList.add(activity);
                    Intent i = new Intent(ConnectionScreen.context,ActivityTypes.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    // TODO I think here must be implemented the link to ActivityTypes

                    break;
                case MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME:
                    Log.e(TAG, "handler - MESSAGE_READ " + MESSAGE_DEVICE_NAME);
                    // save the connected device's name
                    mConnectedDeviceName = msg.getData().getString(DEVICE_NAME);
                    break;
                case MESSAGE_TOAST:
                    Log.e(TAG, "handler - MESSAGE_READ " + MESSAGE_TOAST);
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


}
```

**And the ActivityTypes class:**

```
public class ActivityTypes extends Activity {
    String[] activities = {"Aerobics", "Cycling", "Running", "Strength", "Walking",};
    int[] total_images = {R.drawable.aerobics, R.drawable.cycling, R.drawable.running,
            R.drawable.strength, R.drawable.walking};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
        Spinner spinnerOfActivities = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_activities);
        spinnerOfActivities.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                activities));

    }

    public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int txtViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(ctx, txtViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
            return getCustomView(position, cnvtView, prnt);

        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int pos, View cnvtView, ViewGroup prnt) {
            return getCustomView(pos, cnvtView, prnt);
        }

        public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View mySpinner = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_spinner, parent, false);
            TextView main_text = (TextView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.text_of_activities);
            main_text.setText(activities[position]);
            ImageView left_icon = (ImageView) mySpinner.findViewById(R.id.picture_of_activity);
            left_icon.setImageResource(total_images[position]);
            return mySpinner;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Do you want to exit the application?")
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                        moveTaskToBack(true);
                        }
                }).create().show();


    }
```

**PS: I've put "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" in first bunch of code where I think the link should be done.**

Comment: try this........ Intent i = new Intent(ConnectionScreen.this,ActivityTypes.class);
                    startActivity(i);

Comment: I've tried firstly with `ConnectionScreen.this` but because it is static, it doesn't work. So, that's why I've put `ConnectionScreen.context`.

Comment: have you tried `getApplicationContext()` ???????

Comment: no, how to do that more expicitly?

Comment: use it instead of ConnectionScreen.this

Comment: I written it like this: `Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityTypes.class);` but it says that the method is non-static and it is called in a static cotext.

Comment: Check this answer on how to get the context on a static method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5114361/3465623

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing

```
    Intent i = new Intent(ConnectionScreen.context, ActivityTypes.class);
```

to...

```
   Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityTypes.class);
```

Comment: I cannot use `this` because the Handler in which this part of code is static.